# Limit workers in python multiprocessing pool to 1 CPU each

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, cpu-usage

I'm running a python3 script in parallel on a remote linux server using multiprocessing Pool, that looks something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def somefunc(day):
    #do something
    print(day)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(6) #6 worker processes
    days = range(1,32) #iterate over 31 days (1 month)
    pool.map(somefunc, days)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

When I run `top` all 6 worker processes show a CPU percentage over 100%, usually 500%-600%. I know this is shown as a percent of a single CPU, meaning that each worker is using multiple cores. The server has 32 CPUs total (4 sockets, 4 cores per socket, 2 threads per core), but I am only allowed to use 6 (the server is shared by a few people).

Is there a way to limit each worker process to 1 CPU?

Comment: Are you using Linux?

Comment: @OlvinRoght whoops, it is indeed linux. I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: I think GIL restricts a single worker process to 1 CPU already. However some Python libraries implemented in C allows multiple CPUs usage for single process. Did you use any of those libraries?

Comment: Check [this](http://sorami-chi.hateblo.jp/entry/2016/04/29/000000) link ;)

Comment: Prove it, put [`print(os.getpid())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getpid) into your `def somefunc(day)` to see if get more than `6` different process id.

Comment: @PhilipTzou Thanks. I am not using any other library for parallelization, however I am using some that I believe are implemented in C (numpy, scipy, etc.)

Comment: @stovfl Good point. The output shows only 6 processes: `68706
Day: 1
68707
Day: 3
68708
Day: 5
68709
Day: 7
68710
Day: 9
68711` However, CPU percentages are still high (from `top`: 559%, 534%, 495%, 459%, 447%, 436%)

Comment: @OlvinRoght Thanks! That link helps. I used what was done in "Level N" and modified pool.py, which appears to keep CPU percentages at/below 100%. My one concern: if I assign a PID to a core that is already running a process from another user, will this impact their (or my) processes?

Comment: It's obvious that it will. At all, that's strange that you need to take care about this. Why do you not set up virtual machine for each user of server and not spread cores there?

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately I'm not the owner and the admin is pretty strict (hence the CPU limit). So far assigning cores is doing alright, so I'll keep going with that.